# GNU M4: expand bracketed text?

Tags: gnu, m4

If I run:

```
define(`[x]`,`y')
[x]
=>[x]
```

Nothing happens.. Is there a way to expand brackets in M4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU M4: Define a rule that matches text, and operates on that matched text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206281/gnu-m4-define-a-rule-that-matches-text-and-operates-on-that-matched-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of the macro that you have defined contains non-alphanumeric characters the only way to expand its content is by using the `defn()` built-in macro:

```
define(`[x]',`y')
defn(`[x]')
=> y
```