# GNU M4: Define a rule that matches text, and operates on that matched text?

Tags: gnu, m4

Suppose I have:

```
File:

[x]
```

And I would like to define `m4` macro:

```
define(`\[.*\]`, ...)
```

Question: Is this possible and how does one do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible as you can see in [manual of m4](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/m4.html#Names):

> 3.1 Macro names
>
> A name is any sequence of letters, digits, and the character ‘_’
>   (underscore), where the first character is not a digit. m4 will use
>   the longest such sequence found in the input. If a name has a macro
>   definition, it will be subject to macro expansion (see Macros). Names
>   are case-sensitive.
>
> Examples of legal names are: ‘foo’, ‘_tmp’, and ‘name01’.

The `[` and `]` characters aren't legal in macro definition.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. You *can* define a macro whose name contains non-alphanumeric letters, only you have to invoke it afterwards using `defn()`. Even the official manual suggests [an example with non-alphanumeric macro names](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/html_node/Define.html#index-array). See my answer to **donlan** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57932309/2732907).

Comment: @madmurphy tricky solution, thanks for addition :) But the OP can't use it as (s)he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling adventurous, maybe you could take a look a this experimental feature mentioned in GNU m4 1.4.18's info page :

```
   An experimental feature, which would improve 'm4' usefulness, allows
for changing the syntax for what is a "word" in 'm4'.  You should use:
     ./configure --enable-changeword
if you want this feature compiled in.  The current implementation slows
down 'm4' considerably and is hardly acceptable.  In the future, 'm4'
2.0 will come with a different set of new features that provide similar
capabilities, but without the inefficiencies, so changeword will go away
and _you should not count on it_.
```